# Is rel="noreferrer" needed when the target is a custom framename?

Tags: html, security

I understand that if my link looks like

```
<a href="https://externalsite.com" target="_blank">Dangerous link</a>
```

then that's unsafe because the target site then has access to my site's window object. So I need to add `rel="noreferrer"`. If my link looks like

```
<a href="https://externalsite.com" target="custom name">Is this dangerous?</a>
```

does the same vulnerability still apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `noopener,noreferrer`, `_blank` just opens an unnamed window

The `target` attribute is used as a window name. If you refer to the same target multiple times, that window gets replaced with the new URL.
This will not solve the security issue.

Here is some more info: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Reverse_Tabnabbing
You can try out the example given in that article.

Use `noopener,noreferrer` first. But secondly, don't link to malicous sites